# pg_search negation: how to negate a string with whitespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

I'm using `pg_search` and trying to implement the negation option.

My search form contains a bunch of options, among which selecting key words and selecting words that mustn't be within the keywords. I get all search keywords and all negated keywords and format them for the ps_search method. This is how:

```
def self.find_words(words, not_words)
    if words.present? || not_words.present?

        a_not_words = not_words.gsub(/,/,"").split(" ").each{|l|l.prepend("!")}
        a_words = words.gsub(/,/,"").split(" ")
        a_all = a_not_words + a_words
        my_words = a_all.join(" ")

        pg_search_keywords(my_words)
    else
        order("id DESC")
    end
end
```

This works well with simple words. For example, if someone want all results that contain "kitchen" and "drawer" but not "spoon", this is sent to the pg_search method: `"kitchen drawer !spoon"`

However, many of my keywords contain white spaces and stop words ("de" and "en" in French).

So if a person looks for a "rouleau de cuisine" (rolling pin) but doesn't want "assiette de table" (table dish) that this gets sent to pg_search method: "assiette de table !rouleau !de !cuisine".

This creates 3 problems:

1/ the word "de" is within the search terms and within the negated terms
2/ this looks for the keyword "table", which doesn't exist - only "assiette de table" exists
2/ I can't remove the stop word "de" because then it will start looking for and negating terms that don't exist.

**UPDATE**

This is how I implement pg_search_keywords :

```
pg_search_scope :pg_search_keywords,
                :against => :summery,
                :associated_against => {
                    :keywords => [:keyword]
                },
                :ignoring => :accents,
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :negation => true,
                        :dictionary => 'french'
                    }
                }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is `pg_search_keywords` implemented? Also, how do you plan to input words? If `"kitchen drawer"` are 2 separate words, `"rouleau de cuisine"` cannot be 1 word. So you need to either use `"kitchen,drawer"`, `[kitchen, drawer]` or `"'rouleau de cuisine'"`

Comment: I added the pg_search_keywords in update to my question. Are you saying I can pass an array to pg_search?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should pass a different format for `words` and `not_words` in `self.find_words`. Right now, it looks like you don't have enough information in this method.

Comment: "rouleau de cuisine" must be 1 word because "rouleau" doesn't exist and "de" is a stopword that can also occur in negated terms. What I now send to `pg_search_keywords` is `"assiette de table !rouleau !de !cuisine"` . How should I format the `words` differently from the `not_words`? Are single quotes (as in your answer) the solution, e.g. : `"cuisine, 'rouleau de cuisine', !'assiette de table'"`  ?